# What makes cuLaunchKernel fail with CUDA_ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE?

Tags: cuda, cuda-driver

I'm launching a CUDA kernel I've compiled, using the `cudLaunchKernel()` driver API function. I'm passing my parameters in a `kernelParams` array, and passing `nullptr` for the `extra` argument.

Unfortunately, this fails, with the error: `CUDA_ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE`. Why? I checked the [Driver API documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-driver-api/group__CUDA__EXEC.html) to see how the function might fail in what cases, and **edit** it discusses the failure with `CUDA_ERROR_INVALID_VALUE` (not the same thing). It doesn't discuss the error I get.

Since there is more than one parameter to `cuLaunchKernel()` which is some sort of a handle - what does this failure mean? (And if there are multiple options - what are they?)

Comment: CUDA_ERROR_INVALID_VALUE  and CUDA_ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE are not the same error. You get the error because the handle, i.e. the function is invalid

Comment: @talonmies: Right. Edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility is a failure due to a CUDA driver context switch. You may have inadvertently performed some action which pushes or replaces the current context for the CUDA device; and loaded modules are part of context - so your compiled and loaded kernel can no longer be loaded in the current context. This triggers a `CUDA_ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE` failure.

Assuming this is the case, switch the context before the launch, e.g. this way:

```
cuCtxPushCurrent(my_driver_context);
cuLaunchKernel(/*etc. etc. */);
/* possibly */ cuCtxPopCurrent(NULL);
```

or like so:

```
cuCtxSetCurrent(my_driver_context);
cuLaunchKernel(/*etc. etc. */);
```

Note that you may be risking memory leaks, if you pop and ignore the only reference to a valid context; and you may also risk some other code assuming that the context it has put in place is still the active one.

Answer (score -1):

Well, in my case it was an OOM error (Out of Memory) error which for some reason was not reported as such. When I reduced the batch size of my model it worked. Maybe you should check if this is the case also.

Comment: How sure are you that it was OOM, rather than another potential effect of your changes? Can you post a MWE of this?

Comment: There wasn't any other change from my side (besides the batch size). So, it seems rather reasonable to have been an OOM error.

Answer (score -1):

cuobjdump -symbols myModule.cubin to check whether your function's name had been changed, if so, then add the extern "C" before your device function